# Hotel cancellation during a UK visa process

Tags: visas, uk

My application showed that I would be staying 8 days in the UK. I showed 2 differents hotels. However I cancelled the first day of my hotel booking. But the remaining 7 days are still valid. Is it OK to cancel the hotel booking during the visa application process?

Thank you.

Comment: That depends _completely_ on what your original plans were, and why you changed them. There are very few "mechanical" rules about accommodation bookings; it all comes down to whether or not the totality of your application and circumstances convinces the ECO (and later IO) that you're a genuine visitor.

Comment: Thank you. Application is for PLAB 2 exam because I'll arrive on that night, I cancelled that hotel for just 1 night the other 7 days are still valid.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it OK to cancel the hotel booking during the visa application process?

As long as you adhere to your initial itinerary and have a place to sleep for every day that you're staying in the UK, then yes. It's normal for people to change their hotels between applying for the visas and traveling abroad.